# UrlFetchApp and doPost(e), same code, different projects, different behaviors

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, urlfetch

As I said in the title I got same code on frontend and backend test project (frontend: `UrlFetchApp` | backend: `doPost(e)`) and on dev project.

As I'm quit new in Google Apps Script programming, I did a test project in one gmail account, in order to validate process like fetchUrlApp and doPost communication between two different spreadsheet. The dev project is on another account used as pre-production project.

backend script is deployed as web app new version on both test and dev project
post method is loading a sample basic JSON
on test project I get my JSON on backend side but not on dev project.

Here is the code and results

backend doPost code :

```
function doPost(e) {
    Logger.log("I was called");
    if (typeof e != 'undefined');
    var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("my-backend-id");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Log");
    sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(JSON.stringify(data))
    //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e));
};
```

frontend submit post request :

```
function test_rapide(){
  var data = {"id":"xyz","name":"xy"};
  var ret = makeRequest("https://my-web-app-URL/exec", data);
    
  var content = ret.getContentText();
  Logger.log(content);
};
```

result on test project sucessful :

```
frontend log:
2020-07-03 14:31:33:364 +1100 003093 INFO {"contextPath":"","queryString":"","postData":{"contents":"{\"id\":\"xyz\",\"name\":\"xy\"}","length":24,"name":"postData","type":"application/json"},"parameters":{},"parameter":{},"contentLength":24}

backend log:
2020-07-03 14:31:32:148 +1100 000625 INFO I was called
2020-07-03 14:31:32:322 +1100 000799 INFO [object Object]
2020-07-03 14:31:32:901 +1100 001378 INFO {"id":"xyz","name":"xy"}
```

result on dev project failed :

````
frontend log:
"2020-07-03 15:05:13:886 +1100 000733 INFO Drive Sorry, unable to open the file at this time.Please check the address and try again.Get stuff done with Google Drive Apps in Google Drive make it easy to create, store and share online documents, spreadsheets, presentations and more. Learn more at drive.google.com/start/apps."
backend log:
nothing```
````

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about the difference between `test project` and `dev project` from your question. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, from `result on dev project failed :`, in this case, where can we see the script at?

Comment: @Tanaike sorry for my English as well!
I forgot to mention that test and dev are on two different accounts, and test is to validate some process like the fetchURLApp and doPost, because I'm quite new in Google Apps Script programming

Comment: @Tanaike as I said the script is the same on test and dev, just the result is different.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot still understand about your situation. This is due to my poor understanding. When I could correctly understand about your situation, I would like to think of the issue. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: What's the difference between backend: `test` and `dev` projects?

Comment: @Tanaike the only difference is the test (working code) :
- one free gmail account
the dev (not working)
- on another g suite account

Comment: @TheMaster the `test` is for testing purpose. In this case is only for validating how UrlFetchApp request in post method is working on frontend and in backend the return of the doPost() method (still in test).
the `dev` is the full application that will integrate the UrlFetchApp / doPost communication between the frontend and backend.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So I cannot think of the solution. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. By the way, can I ask you about the detail of settings of Web Apps you deployed?

Comment: Can't help you without intricate details of structure of your `test` and `dev`. As tanaike suspects, *can I ask you about the detail of settings of Web Apps you deployed?*: **Questions about web applications must include how the app is published: 1. Execute as"Me"/"User accessing the web-app". 2.Access:" Anyone"/"Anyone even anonymous"** from [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script-web-application/info). Tanaike suspects you're missing "even anonymous" on the `/dev`. Is that a bullseye?